# Can I know what others login via ssh have done and what they are doing on my Linux?

Tags: ssh, root, sshd

As a root user, can I know what other ssh-login users have done and what they are doing on my Linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `who` (or `w`) command to see who is currently logged in. You can use the `last` command to see a history of people who have logged in lately in your box (even the ones that are not anymore logged in).

If you see nothing in both the commands above, it means that someone with root privileges cleared the history.

However, you cannot know what are someone doing *currently*. What you can is see their `.bash_history` (assuming they use bash) file and see their last commands. Note that you'll only find here the commands the user run if they logged out from the shell.

Comment: `who` outputs some lines as `user     pts/NUM      DATE  TIME (:0.0)` . For some lines, it's not (:0.0) but (IP Address). Does (:0.0) mean dead?

Comment: No, those are displays. It basically means that someone is connected with some mechanism that Linux understand as a physical login. These can be: A physical access with a keyboard connected to the box, a service like `iLO/DRAC` which grants the user a way to interact with the box like they were physically there, etc.

Comment: OMG, I saw lots of connections at some unexpected time (listed by `w`.)

Comment: If they are still in, kill them all as I answered in your other question and change the password ASAP.

Comment: So if I got what you mean, for `display:0.0`, they are local connections and I don't need to be worried.

Answer (score 1):

`w` is the answer.
And if you want to see the command history you can always check their `~/.bash_history` files.

Example `w`:

```
$w
 17:13:38 up 1 day,  3:45,  3 users,  load average: 1.57, 1.24, 1.02
USER     TTY        LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
claudio  :0        Tue13   ?xdm?   5:42m  0.40s gnome-session
claudio  pts/0     Tue14   24:04m  0.20s  0.20s bash
claudio  pts/1     Tue15    0.00s  0.08s  0.00s w
```